# NDK not shown in SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-ndk, android-sdk-manager

I want to download NDK by SDK manager like:
[google developer.android.com ...](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#download-ndk)

but my SDK manager didn't show NDK or even API 25.
what should I do?
for every simple and empty activity, I got this error

> Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
>   Install Build Tools 25.0.0, update version in build file and sync project
> Open File

[image: SDK manager in google Studio 2.3]

Comment: Could you file a bug? We've seen this issue a few times but have never received enough information to do anything about it. http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs

Comment: @DanAlbert maybe it's because of my Internet IP Address and International law about some countries.

Comment: Did you file a bug? I can't actually help you with this, but I can assign your bug to someone that can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is about Android Studio proxy settings and

> Access Denied

for Iranian's **IP**

Answer (score 0):

(Probably not relevant for OP but can help others)
SDK Manager shows only the relevant packages to your environment.
So, if your platform architecture is Linux 32-bit, you'll not see NDK options since Linux 32-bit NDK version are no longer supported by google.

Solutions:
1. Get a Windows/Mac System or 64-bit Linux (can be virtual as well).
2. Use an older NDK version for 32-bit Linux systems: https://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86.bin

If you're on Linux and not sure what is your OS arch, you can use:
`$ uname -i`
if the output is `x86_64` then that's a 64-bit OS, otherwise - 32.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the future, folks, disable your VPN that you forgot running in the background.

I had a VPN (Israel) and NDK didn't show up

Mac OS